# Files show as being all on one line in Notepad/Mercurial hosted repo

Tags: mercurial

I noticed some files were showing up in Mercurial as being all on one line. Others (most) don't.

When opening one that does and one that doesn't in Notepad I can see the same problem, Notepad shows the file's whitespace to be all over the place and little squares where new lines should be.

What's going on and how can I fix it? I suspect it to be something to do with the file encoding.

*I'm not really sure what to tag this as - it's not really a Mercurial problem*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have the wrong line endings encoded in the files. Quick google pulls up [this page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EOLTranslationPlan) which may be of use.

Try opening the files in a more advanced editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and then turn on display of line ending characters to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: That is indeed the case. I'm trying to follow the steps on the page you link to but it isn't changing the CRs to CRLFs when I update. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hm, forget Mercurial - Notepad++ > Edit > EOL Conversion > Windows Format